# "getText" syntax is not working and it's showing error

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

"getText" syntax is not working and it's showing error.

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        String usernam = username.getText().toString();
        String passwordd = password.getText().toString();
        if(usernam.trim().equals("")|| passwordd.trim().equals(""))
        {
            z = "Please enter Username and Password";
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                con = connectionclass(un, pass, db, ip);
                if (con == null)
                {
                    z = "Check Tour Internet Access!";
                }
                else
                {
                    String query = "select * from login where user_name= '" + usernam.toString() + "' and pass_word = ' " + passwordd.toString();
                    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                    if(rs.next())
                    {
                        z = "Login successful";
                        isSuccess = true;
                        con.close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        z = "Invalid Credentials";
                        isSuccess = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                isSuccess = false;
                z = ex.getMessage();
            }
        }
        return z;
    }
```

i am not able to get answer, expected answer is, should able retrieve username, password and match it to the username password which we enter, but now i couldn't able to match both.

Comment: What does not work? What do you expect? What happens instead?

Comment: Please explain ["is not working"](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/).

Comment: BTW don't use concatenation while creating SQL query or you will be introducing [sql-injection vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). Use PreparedStatement instead https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html.

Comment: String usernam = username.getText().toString();
String passwordd = password.getText().toString();                                          these two lines are showing error

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: May be its because you are trying to access the UI textViews within the doInBackground method of AsyncTask. try reading the values from the textView in the preExecute() method.

Comment: How to do it @PaulPJoby

Comment: wait I will show you how to get it done

Comment: Method getText must be called from the UI thread, currently inferred thread is worker thread less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info:Ensures that a method which expects to be called on a specific thread, is actually called from that thread. For example, calls on methods in widgets should always be made on the UI thread.  Issue id: WrongThread @LutzHorn

Comment: Please add android and other android related tags to you question otherwise this question gonna be removed

Comment: Use [edit] option to provide more relevant information like error message. Don't put them in comments, don't force people which may be willing to help you to search for relevant information all over the place, let them be gathered in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

 private String username="";
 private String password="";

 public MyAsyncTask(String user, String pass)
 {
    this.username = user;
    this.password = pass;
 }

 protected void onPreExecute() {

 }

 protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {
     // Some long-running task like downloading an image.
     // No UI related work here.. or else it will crash

 }



 protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
     // This method is executed in the UIThread
     // with access to the result of the long running task

 }
}
```

Now when calling the asynctask in your Activity do this

```
// Its inside the Activity Class 
MyAsyncTask asd = new MyAsyncTask(username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());

asd.execute("");
```

Pass the values of the EditText while calling the AsyncTask itself in the activity

Comment: Cannot resolve method .getText() error @Paul P Joby

Comment: you should use that method with the textView name that you have used in the activity

Comment: you should declare the TextView for username and password in main activity by using findViewById(R.id.nameoftextview) method

Comment: please approve the answer if you think that was the issue @TharminiAnandasivanesan

Comment: sorry                                                                                                                               login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlogin);
        username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);                          Are you telling about this part

Comment: Yes .. then inside the onClickListener of the login button... MyAsyncTask asd = new MyAsyncTask(username.getText().toString(),password.getText().toString());

asd.execute("");

Comment: make the username and password textView as final

Comment: How @Paul P Joby

Comment: see use the final keyword in java like this inside the onCreate method ----->>>> final EditText username  = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);

Comment: i added but its not came correctly still getText(); is in red color @Paul P Joby

Comment: what can i do @Paul P Joby

Comment: just try build and clean your project thats gonna solve you issue and make sure there is no variable with the same name as username may be that way its conflicting .... try name everything uniquely ... that may help and uses .... textviewname.getText(); .. it will and should work.